# Display launch image in Landscape Mode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4, landscape

I am using Cocos2d and Xcode 4. My app currently displays the launch image in portrait mode, then switches to landscape so the image is on its side, then launches the app. How can I:
1. Make it run the launch image for a certain duration.
2. Make it display it in Landscape mode, not portrait.
Any Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just make your image in landscape and use that?  Basically like what zeiteisen said.

Just open up gimp or photoshop and make a new image: 480w X 320h.

Comment: thanks man, I was just thinking about my question a while ago and found an answer, and since i have to mark an answer, yours was it.

Answer (score 0):

To make your launch image display in landscape mode, simply append `-Landscape` to its filename (e.g. change `LaunchImage.png` to `LaunchImage-Landscape.png`).

As for showing your launch image for a certain duration, you have two options: display a "launch image" view controller initially and dismiss it after the desired duration (allows you to fade the image out, etc.), or simply call `sleep()` in your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. It's important to note that you have no control over how long the OS displays your launch image before control is passed to your app delegate—you need to take this into consideration.

Comment: What aspect of it didn't work? The landscape launch image or the delay? Ensure you are following the naming conventions detailed here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12

Comment: that link doesn't go anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Just rotate the Default.png in your favourite image editor like Photoshop.

Comment: I already have it rotated, it just resizes it to fit in portrait mode.

Comment: Thats odd. This method works fine for me. Did you reimported the image?

Comment: yeah. do you mean like removing it from the resources file and putting it back in?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by changing the view to landscape in Interface Builder. Mine is still animating though from the initial portrait orientation of the Window (not settable to landscape in IB).

Comment: how to do your idea in cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

In `AppDelegate applicatio:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` there is a call to
`[director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]]`. In there, it shamelessly loads the splash screen again and displays it rotated by 90 degrees:

```
    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) {
        background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
        background.rotation = 90;
    }
```

Removing this fixes the rotating splash screen problem.